# What is the different between introspective and introverted?

Tags: word-choice

What is the different between introspective and introverted ? Is it same meaning? 
When I search on Cambridge's dic, there is no introverted.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ko/%EC%82%AC%EC%A0%84/%EC%98%81%EC%96%B4/introvert?q=introverted

Comment: You need to look for the root word "introvert".

Comment: Oh I did, Is it same?

Comment: A person who is an "introvert" *is* introverted. Noun vs the verb. The adjectives that describe the two are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Introspective means a person who likes to look inward, look inside him- or herself and think. Anyone can be introspective at times in their life.

introverted (noun, introvert) is a personality type, someone who is quiet and does not show much outward emotion. Introverts can be difficult people in terms of communicating with others.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. If I try to describe myself as an introspective person, is it weird?

Comment: @Ted No, that is not weird. That may just be the way you are. It's not negative in and of itself at all.